# How to simulate http post request and parse html response in ruby

Tags: ruby, http, post

I am trying to simulate an http request related to the form on this webpage :
http://www.ei.applipub-fft.fr/eipublic/competitionRecherche.do
I then need to parse the response html.

I was trying to use gem 'webmock' and 'rest-client'. So after studying the original http request I tried something like that :

```
def post
  stub_request(:post, "http://www.ei.applipub-fft.fr/eipublic/competitionRecherche.do").
      with(:body => {"data"=>{"dispatch"=>"filtrer", "hoi_atp"=>"T", "dtdate"=>"30/12/2015", "mois"=>"12", "multi_lig_cod"=>"0", "lig_cno_1"=>"01", "bidf"=>"0", "imit_categ_age"=>"0", "hoiCtmcDames"=>"T"}},
           :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*; q=0.5, application/xml', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length'=>'174', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
      to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

 resp = RestClient.post('http://www.ei.applipub-fft.fr/eipublic/competitionRecherche.do', "data[dispatch]=filtrer&data[hoi_atp]=T&data[dtdate]=30/12/2015&data[mois]=12&data[multi_lig_cod]=0&data[lig_cno_1]=01&data[bidf]=0&data[imit_categ_age]=0&data[hoiCtmcDames]=T",
  :content_type => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
 puts resp a
end
```

But I cant get my hand on a proper html response.
Can someone explain how all this works ?

Comment: this should help http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

Comment: this link doesnt work : "error establishing an internet connection"

Answer (score 0):

I would usually do it with HTTParty gem. It allows you to write the post request in Ruby.
Example:

```
HTTParty.post('http://example.com/post_here', 
  body: { subject: 'This is the screen name', 
          description: 'This is the description for the problem'
        }.to_json,
  headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html)

Post:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/search")

# Shortcut
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"q" => "My query", "per_page" => "50"})

# Full control
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({"q" => "My query", "per_page" => "50"})

response = http.request(request)
```

Dealing with response object:

```
response.code             # => 301
response.body             # => The body (HTML, XML, blob, whatever)
# Headers are lowercased
response["cache-control"] # => public, max-age=2592000
```